# Accessing an object property with a "#" in the property name in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, escaping, special-characters

I have an array of objects that comes back from a REST API call. The objects are "name" and "#text". Terrible names, I know, but I have no control over that. How do I get the value of both? I can get the value of #text for one entry via select -ExpandProperty `#text. I'm trying to push all the entries through the pipeline for further processing and coming up short on how to reference the #text in subsequent pipeline commands. I've tried selecting out the name and #text and renaming #text to something like 'value' but the back-tick escape used in a computed variable like below doesn't appear to work:

```
$bxml.properties.property|select @{n='Name';e={$_.name}},@{n='Value';e={$_.`#text}}
```

Anybody have suggestions as to how to code this so I can use the value of #text further down the pipeline?

Comment: `$_.'#text'` works for me

Comment: @Asnivor - post as an answer? I knew it had to be something easy I was missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the value in ' '

```
$bxml.properties.property|select @{n='Name';e={$_.name}},@{n='Value';e={$_.'#text'}}
```